# how to have blank value in options_for_select if no recorded value, show chosen value if record exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is sort of a silly questions since I do have a way of solving this but I am wondering ig there is a better way to doing this.  I notice rails has many magical ways to doing thangs that "just worked"..... So I wonder if there is a better, rails way, to do thiss

In an `options_for_select` form helper, I would like to have a value chosen if there is a value already exists in the database, else, blank.

The following has a blank value no matter if something exists or not:

```
<%= ff.select :image_file_id, options_for_select(@image_files.map { |image| [image.id, {'data-img-src'=>image.image_file_url(:thumb)}]}), {:include_blank => 'Choose None'}, class: "image-picker" %>
```

This has a default value of whats exists in the database, but if nothing exists in the database, it shows the first value in the databases:

```
<%= ff.select :image_file_id, options_for_select(@image_files.map { |image| [image.id, {'data-img-src'=>image.image_file_url(:thumb)}]}, ff.object.image_file_id), {:include_blank => 'Choose None'}, class: "image-picker" %>
```

I read prompt would do what I want, showing blank if record not exists, shows value if value exists, but if didn't seem to work any way I tried.

Aside from doing and `if` `else` statement, if there a way to do this in one rails magic line?

Comment: An `if` `else` statement is much more readable than some cryptic one-liner IMO

Answer (score 0):

`include_blank: @image_files.empty? ? 'Choose None' : nil`

In fact it's also `if` `else`